# Excel file generated with php can be seen in Mac but not on Windows

Tags: php, excel

With a php script I generated an excel. This has been worked until a few days ago, now when I download the file in Windows, Excel does not display the content. But if I open it with Mac the contect it's displayed correctly.
I think it can be related with an office's update issue.

I have tried it with various content-type and with different headers, but the behavior is the same.

The code I am using to print this file is:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"');
header('content-disposition: attachment;filename="name_file.xls"');

echo '<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>content</td></tr>
      .....
      .....
    </thead>
 </table>';
```

Comment: You realise that your'e not actually generating an Excel file, simply a file that has a .xls extension.... you're really generating an html file

Comment: You are writing HTML not Excel

Comment: I would generate a CSV. Both versions of office should open that fine, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php.

Comment: Exactly, I'm writing a html for a table, this has been always being interpreted correctly by Excel, distributing content in the cells.